# Using the same Vue variable in a different place gives error

Tags: vue.js

I have an array with translations that in the root component, `this.$root.translations`, and the following situation

```
<div class="fashion-lounge-price ">
     <h6><span v-if="item['service_price_discounted'] > 0">{{
         item['service_price_discounted'] > 0 ? item['service_price']+ (item['service_price_max'] > item['service_price'] ? '-'+ item['service_price_max'] : '' ) : ''}} 
{{ this.$root.translations['t_lei'] }}</span>

{{item['service_price_discounted'] > 0 ? item['service_price_discounted']+(item['service_price_max'] > item['service_price'] ? '-'+((((item['service_price'] - item['service_price_discounted'])/item['service_price']) * 100)/100) * item['service_price_max'] : '') : item['service_price']+(item['service_price_max'] > item['service_price'] ? '-'+item['service_price_max'] : '' )}}
{{ this.$root.translations['t_lei'] }}
 </h6> 
</div>
```

The first time I use `{{ this.$root.translations['t_lei'] }}` works without an issue. However, its second occurence (above the `</h6>`) throws this error:
`[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this is undefined"`
However, using it anywhere else in the component, except for that place, doesn't throw any error, and works.

Is there anything I am missing with this?

Comment: you don't have to write `this` in the template area. Remove it and try again please.

Comment: Also, your extensive in-template logic makes it very unreadable. Have you considered offloading those to computed properties instead?

Comment: @wittgenstein oh, that worked. Had no idea that was the actual issue! If you want you can write it as a separate answer so I can pick it.

Comment: @Terry I will definitely do that, after I figure out the translations stuff! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to write `this` in the template area. Remove it and try again please.

With `this` you can access all methods or reactive data in your script-area. I hope you can learn more about it from the [vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data)